# Deployment issue:no custom field named Case.SourceId found

Tags: deployment

I've trying to deploy profiles from one org to another (org to org migration through AutoRabit) when I got this strange error **no custom field named Case.SourceId found**. There is no place in these profiles where Case objects and its fields has been referred. Any idea as to how this can be resolved?

Comment: Hey @sagnik, is the profile a new profile in the source org, or does it exist in both orgs and you are just migrating some changes to an existing profile?

Comment: This is an existing profile and i'm just migrating some changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [known issue of Salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000001ALuAAM) and they have already released the patch for this.

either enable "Live Agent" in the target org or 
remove "case.sourceId" field and deploy

Comment: okk. How do I remove case.sourceId?

Comment: open case.object with any text editor and remove sourceId.

Comment: Thanks for assisting. So what I understand from this is in the source org we have case object with sourceId while in destination it is not present. So you are suggesting to edit the metadata xml of case object of my source org ,remove the sourceId field and then deploy to destination, right?

Comment: That is correct or enable live agent in your target org

Comment: I enabled 'Live Agent' on target org . This time it threw another strange error "no customField named SocialPersona.AreWeFollowing found"!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things going wrong here, each with a potentially different solution. So more info on the profiles and the state of each org would be helpful.

1. You are deploying a new profile that contains a reference to the SourceId field of the Case object, and deploying that profile to an org that doesn't have the SourceId field.
2. You are deploying a change to a profile that contains a reference to the SourceId field and the target org doesn't have that field.
3. You are deploying a change to a profile that contains a reference to the SourceId field, and the target doesn't allow changes to that field for some reason.
4. You are experiencing a genuine Salesforce bug :)